# __FILE__ Magic Constant in PHP on Windows Not Returning Slashes

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP. I'm troubleshooting a PHP app that was developed and running in Apache. We are moving the app to a windows server running php under IIS.  The top of the index.php has the following code which is throwing an error:

```html
<?php
 $FileArray = explode("/",__FILE__);
 include_once("/" . $FileArray[1] . "/" . $FileArray[2] . "/theapp/api/MainTemplate.inc.php");
 include_once("/" . $FileArray[1] . "/" . $FileArray[2] . "/theapp/class/User.class.php");

?>
```

When I inspect the __FILE_ using an alert, it shows the entire path without any slashes.

```html
<?php
echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo 'alert("'.__FILE__.'")';
echo '</script>';
?>
```

So instead of showing **c:\directory\subdirectory\theapp\index.php** it shows **c:directorysubdirectorytheappindex.php**
I guessing this is the reason I am getting the following error:
**Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\Directory\subdirectory\theapp\index.php on line 3**
What do I need to do here to get this working?

Comment: `echo 'alert("'.json_encode(__FILE__).'")';` This is not a `__FILE__` issue it's a " `\\` is an escape character which you need to escape if you're going to pass it to JavaScript" issue.

Comment: Yes, the backslash is the directory separator character on windows. Replace ```explode('/', __FILE__);``` with ```explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, __FILE__);```

Comment: @BenGuest - Thanks that fixed the issue of it seeing the slashes. Is there a way to set the value to use a relative path? In the original it parsed the _FILE_ array for the first 2 values. However the nesting is different on the new dev server. I'm concerned that if I go into every place and hard code the nesting I'll be setting myself up for a problem in the future.

Comment: You should expect the files you want to include to be in the same location relative to index.php. You need to maintain some folder structure between your dev environment and production. If there is no leading ```"/"``` in your include, PHP will use a relative path from ```index.php```.

Answer (score 3):

Undefined offset notice is displayed because you use first and second index of array "$FileArray", before this you should verify that variable exists(isset method)

If you want to inspect PHP code use var_dump(), example:

```
<?php
   var_dump(__FILE__);
```

Don't close PHP tag in this case. You don't see '\' signs, because backslash is escape sign in JavaScript(and PHP), example:

```js
alert("this\is\sample\text");
```

If you want to display string with escape sign you must use double backslash:

```js
alert("this\\is\\sample\\text");
```

Simple run:

```
<?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("'.str_replace('\\', '\\\\', __FILE__).'")';
    echo '</script>';
```

This is analogous to change backslashes to slashes:

```
<?php
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("'.str_replace('\\', '/', __FILE__).'")';
    echo '</script>';
```

Backslash is escape sign in double quotes strings only.

Answer (score 0):

As some have said, it's an issue related to '\'.

You can simply do this:

```
$FileArray = explode("/", addslashes(__FILE__));
```